# google api oauth 2.0 linux root

Tags: java, webserver, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-oauth-java-client

I am using the Google Sheets API for a Web Application that visualizes a excel sheet into a diagram. This works great if I run the server locally and use my browser to access the google consent screen...

But if I upload the webpage to my linux root server where I only have console access, I cant use a browser to give the machine access to the google api.

I used the google api java example to write this code.

My Question is now: How do I give my webserver access to the google API, I tried the service account, but if I use the json I get from the service account as the client/secret it doesnt work at all.

Here is my code. Maybe its an easy fix I am just to stupid to see.

```
package de.promolitor.wabcodiagramviewer;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.*;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

import de.promolitor.wabcodiagramviewer.data.DiagramNode;
import de.promolitor.wabcodiagramviewer.data.DiagramNodeTitles;
import de.promolitor.wabcodiagramviewer.data.WabcoExcelProperties;
import de.promolitor.wabcodiagramviewer.utils.SheetParsing;

import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

public class GoogleConnection {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"),
            ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    private static Sheets service;

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials at
     * ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);

    static {
        try {
            System.out.println("GoogleConnection: Absolut Path for Sheet API: " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * 
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {

        String relativeWebPath = "/resources/" + "client_secret.json";
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getContext();
        String absoluteDiskPath = servletContext.getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
        System.out.println("GoogleConnection: Absolut Path: " + absoluteDiskPath);
        File file = new File(absoluteDiskPath);

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
                clientSecrets, SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY).setAccessType("offline").build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println("Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Sheets API client service.
     * 
     * @return an authorized Sheets API client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public static void initializeSheetService() throws IOException {
        service = getSheetsService();
    }

    public static List<WabcoExcelProperties> getSheetsData(String Id) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("GoogleConnection: Loading sheetData for SheetNames!");
        Spreadsheet responseSheet = null;
        try {
            responseSheet = service.spreadsheets().get(Id).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<Sheet> values = responseSheet.getSheets();
        List<WabcoExcelProperties> sheetData = new ArrayList<WabcoExcelProperties>();
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        for (Sheet sheet : values) {
            sheetData.add(gson.fromJson(jp.parse(sheet.get("properties").toString()), WabcoExcelProperties.class));
        }
        System.out.println("GoogleConnection: Loading sheetData for SheetNames! COMPLETE");
        return sheetData;
    }

    public static List<DiagramNode> getDiagramNodeInformation(String spreadsheetId, String range, String sheetName)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("GoogleConnection: PARSING DIAGRAM NODE INFORMATION");
        List<DiagramNode> nodes = new ArrayList<DiagramNode>();

        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, range).execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();

        try {
            System.out.println("GoogleConnection: Trying to load titles!");
            List<Object> data = values.get(0);
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            DiagramNodeTitles dnt = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{diagramNodeTitles}",
                    DiagramNodeTitles.class);
            dnt.setNeworder((String) data.get(SheetParsing.NEWORDER));
            dnt.setPa((String) data.get(SheetParsing.PA));
            dnt.setPb((String) data.get(SheetParsing.PB));
            dnt.setPc((String) data.get(SheetParsing.PC));
            dnt.setPd((String) data.get(SheetParsing.PD));
            dnt.setKeytask((String) data.get(SheetParsing.KEYTASK));
            dnt.setPhase((String) data.get(SheetParsing.PHASE));
            dnt.setPrecedentstep((String) data.get(SheetParsing.PRECEDENTSTEP));
            dnt.setId((String) data.get(SheetParsing.ID));
            dnt.setType((String) data.get(SheetParsing.TYPE));
            dnt.setTask((String) data.get(SheetParsing.TASK));
            dnt.setDeliverable((String) data.get(SheetParsing.DELIVERABLE));
            dnt.setRole((String) data.get(SheetParsing.ROLE));
            dnt.setApqelement((String) data.get(SheetParsing.APQPELEMENT));
            dnt.setSuppliers((String) data.get(SheetParsing.SUPPLIERS));
            dnt.setInput((String) data.get(SheetParsing.INPUT));
            dnt.setProcessdescription((String) data.get(SheetParsing.PROCESSDESCRIPTION));
            dnt.setOutput((String) data.get(SheetParsing.OUTPUT));
            dnt.setCustomer((String) data.get(SheetParsing.CUSTOMER));
            dnt.setR((String) data.get(SheetParsing.R));
            dnt.setA((String) data.get(SheetParsing.A));
            dnt.setS((String) data.get(SheetParsing.S));
            dnt.setC((String) data.get(SheetParsing.C));
            dnt.setI((String) data.get(SheetParsing.I));
            dnt.setDeliverabletemplate((String) data.get(SheetParsing.DELIVERABLETEMPLATE));
            dnt.setWorkinstruction((String) data.get(SheetParsing.WORKINSTRUCTION));
            dnt.setBestpractice((String) data.get(SheetParsing.BESTPRACTICE));
            dnt.setUsefullinks((String) data.get(SheetParsing.USEFULLINKLS));

            System.out.println("GoogleConnection: LOADING TITLES COMPLETE");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("GoogleConnection: ERROR WHILE LOADING TITLES");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < values.size() - 1; i++) {
            try {
                List<Object> data = values.get(i);
                System.out.println("GoogleConnection: Parsing Row" + (i + 1) + " Row Size: " + data.size());
                String Id = (String) data.get(SheetParsing.ID);
                double newOrderCell = Double.parseDouble((String) data.get(SheetParsing.NEWORDER));
                if (newOrderCell == 0.0 || ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.TYPE)).equals("delete")
                        || ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.ID)).startsWith("<")) {
                    if (newOrderCell == 0.0)
                        System.out.println("New Order Cell == 0");
                    if (((String) data.get(SheetParsing.TYPE)).equals("delete"))
                        System.out.println("cell should be deleted...");
                    if (((String) data.get(SheetParsing.ID)).startsWith("<"))
                        System.out.println("Cell starts with <... so we do not care.");
                    continue;
                }
                if (DataManager.debug)
                    System.out.println("Adding NewOrder: " + newOrderCell);
                int phase = 0;
                int newOrder = 0;
                try {
                    phase = Integer.parseInt(((String) data.get(SheetParsing.PHASE)));
                    newOrder = Integer.parseInt(((String) data.get(SheetParsing.NEWORDER)));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                }

                boolean PA = false;
                boolean PB = false;
                boolean PC = false;
                boolean PD = false;
                boolean KEYTASK = false;
                String PRECEDENTSTEP = "";
                String ID = "";
                String TYPE = "";
                String TASK = "";
                String ROLE = "";
                String APQPELEMENT = "";
                String SUPPLIERS = "";
                String INPUT = "";
                String PROCESSDESCRIPTION = "";
                String OUTPUT = "";
                String CUSTOMER = "";
                String R = "";
                String A = "";
                String S = "";
                String C = "";
                String I = "";
                String DELIVERABLETEMPLATE = "";
                String WORKINSTRUCTION = "";
                String BESTPRACTICE = "";
                String USEFULLINKS = "";
                try {
                    PA = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.PA)).toLowerCase().contains("x");
                    PB = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.PB)).toLowerCase().contains("x");
                    PC = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.PC)).toLowerCase().contains("x");
                    PD = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.PD)).toLowerCase().contains("x");
                    KEYTASK = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.KEYTASK)).toLowerCase().contains("x");

                    PRECEDENTSTEP = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.PRECEDENTSTEP));
                    ID = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.ID));
                    TYPE = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.TYPE));
                    TASK = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.TASK));
                    ROLE = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.ROLE));
                    APQPELEMENT = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.APQPELEMENT));
                    SUPPLIERS = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.SUPPLIERS));
                    INPUT = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.INPUT));
                    PROCESSDESCRIPTION = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.PROCESSDESCRIPTION));
                    OUTPUT = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.OUTPUT));
                    CUSTOMER = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.CUSTOMER));
                    R = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.R));
                    A = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.A));
                    S = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.S));
                    C = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.C));
                    I = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.I));
                    DELIVERABLETEMPLATE = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.DELIVERABLETEMPLATE));
                    WORKINSTRUCTION = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.WORKINSTRUCTION));
                    BESTPRACTICE = ((String) data.get(SheetParsing.BESTPRACTICE));
                    USEFULLINKS = (String) data.get(SheetParsing.USEFULLINKLS);
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                }

                DiagramNode node = new DiagramNode(sheetName, newOrder, PA, PB, PC, PD, KEYTASK, phase, PRECEDENTSTEP,
                        ID, TYPE, TASK, ROLE, APQPELEMENT, SUPPLIERS, INPUT, PROCESSDESCRIPTION, OUTPUT, CUSTOMER, R, A,
                        S, C, I, DELIVERABLETEMPLATE, WORKINSTRUCTION, BESTPRACTICE, USEFULLINKS);
                System.out.println("GoogleConnection: Adding Node: " + node);
                nodes.add(node);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("GoogleConnection: ERROR IN ROW.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        System.out.println("GoogleConnection: Create Node: " + nodes);
        return nodes;
    }

    // public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // // Build a new authorized API client service.
    // initializeSheetService();
    //
    // List<WabcoExcelProperties> sheetData =
    // getSheetsData(SheetParsing.SPREADSHEETID);
    // System.out.println(sheetData.get(1).getTitle());
    //
    // }

}
```

***UPDATE***
Error was: "Not authorized"

After SEVERAL more hours of trouble shooting I finally manged to fix it though. I tried a lot with a p12 Keyfile and a "Google Service Account" but that also didnt seem to work. I also got "Not authorized" all the way.

I tried the service account with the complete json file before. At least I think...

As I changed to it the 2nd time I must have mode something different.

I added:

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(absoluteDiskPathToJson)).createScoped(SCOPES);
//Added the sheets with credentials.
Sheets sheets = Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();
```

And that SOMEHOW worked. I was sure I already tried it with the json file + service account before, but I might did a small mistake somewhere down the line.
I also tried pass the service account the access rights of my main account, which also didnt work, or I did an error somewhere. I added the needed access rights to the service account now aswell. After 12 hours of troubleshooting it is now working without issues.

Comment: Did you receive any kind of error message?

Comment: posted an update. I still dont really know where all my issues were or what I exactly did wrong and where, but it is working.
Thx for responding!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp class of Google APIs.

AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp's browse method has the following code:

```
public static void browse(String url) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(url);
    // Ask user to open in their browser using copy-paste
    System.out.println("Please open the following address in your browser:");
    System.out.println("  " + url);
```

which prints the URL on the console, not in the log file.

Check for the console logs/catalina.out logs. There the same lines will be printed and then you can proceed further with this.